# Trouble with types in arrays and attempting to sort things into tables

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, types

Basically this code should produce two tables, one containing every type in the array, which works fine, and another containing the summed up totals of materials with the same name

e.g. say you enter two instances of red paint (10 sqr ft. and 5 sqr ft.) and two instances of blue paint (30 sqr ft and 10 sqr ft.) then the second table should show...

> red paint: 15 sqr ft
>
> blue paint: 40 sqr ft.

...but currently it only adds together the materials with the same name as the first one in the array and then just spits out each individual material, e.g.

> red paint: 15 sqr ft.
>
> blue paint: 30 sqr ft.
>
> blue paint: 10 sqr ft.

I've tried a few different things but can't seem to get it to work properly, anyone have any ideas?

```
function wallTableFunction(){
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("wallTable"),
        table = "<table border='1'>" +
            "<thread><th>Room</th><th>Surface</th><th>Material</th><th>Width</th><th>Height</th><th>Surface Area</th></thread>";

    var totalDiv = document.getElementById("wallTotals"),
        totalTable = "<table border='1'>" +
            "<thread><th>Material</th><th>TOTAL</th></thread>";

    for(var i = 0, j = walls.length; i<j; i++){
        table += walls[i].tableRow();
    }

    for(var k = 0, l = otherWallArray.length; k<l; k++){
        totalTable += otherWallArray[k].totalRow();
    }

    table += "</table>";
    totalTable += "</table>";

    tableDiv.innerHTML = table;
    totalDiv.innerHTML = totalTable;
}

var wallTotals = function(){
    for(var i = 0, j = walls.length; i<j; i++){
        var wallMaterialFinal = walls[i].material;
        var wallResultTotal = walls[i].result;
        var a = new wallThing(wallMaterialFinal, wallResultTotal);
        wallThingArray.push(a);
    }
    otherWallArray[0] = wallThingArray[0];
    wallThingArray[0] = null;
};

window.onload = function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("wallArray")!== null){
        var storedWalls = JSON.parse(localStorage["wallArray"]);
        for(var i = 0, j = storedWalls.length; i<j; i++){
            var wallRoom = storedWalls[i].room;
            var wallSurf = storedWalls[i].surface;
            var wallMat = storedWalls[i].material;
            var wallWidth = storedWalls[i].width;
            var wallHeight = storedWalls[i].height;
            var wallResult = storedWalls[i].result;
            var a = new Wall(wallRoom, wallSurf, wallMat, wallWidth, wallHeight, wallResult);
            walls.push(a);
        }
        wallTotals();

        for(var q = 0, r = wallThingArray.length; q<r; q++){
            if(wallThingArray[q] != null) {
                for (var s = 0, t = otherWallArray.length; s<t; s++) {
                    if(wallThingArray[q] != null) {
                        if (wallThingArray[q].material == otherWallArray[s].material) {
                            otherWallArray[s].result += wallThingArray[q].result;
                            wallThingArray[q] = null;
                        } else {
                            otherWallArray.push(wallThingArray[q]);
                            wallThingArray[q] = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        wallTableFunction();
    }
};
```

Comment: Please isolate the specific issue.

Comment: This is a small part of a larger program, this is about as specific as I can make it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're trying to summarize, there is a logical flaw here:

```
for(var q = 0, r = wallThingArray.length; q<r; q++){
    if(wallThingArray[q] != null) {
        for (var s = 0, t = otherWallArray.length; s<t; s++) {
            if(wallThingArray[q] != null) {
                if (wallThingArray[q].material == otherWallArray[s].material) {
                    otherWallArray[s].result += wallThingArray[q].result;
                    wallThingArray[q] = null;
                } else {
                    otherWallArray.push(wallThingArray[q]);
                    wallThingArray[q] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The innermost `else` will mean that if the item doesn't match the first item in `otherWallArray`, it will always be pushed into `otherWallArray`. What you want instead is to only push into `otherWallArray` after you've looped through *every* row looking for a match and found nothing:

```
for (var q = 0, r = wallThingArray.length; q<r; q++) {
    var foundMatch = false;
    for (var s = 0, t = otherWallArray.length; s<t; s++) {
        if (wallThingArray[q].material == otherWallArray[s].material) {
            otherWallArray[s].result += wallThingArray[q].result;
            foundMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!foundMatch) {
        otherWallArray.push(wallThingArray[q]);
        wallThingArray[q] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried your code it threw an error saying wallThingArray[q] on the 4th line of your code is null.

Comment: I'd remove all those `wallThingArray[q] = null;` lines, personally. That way you don't have to do all the null checks. If you really will have null values in the array, you can put that null-checking `if` statement in your original back in there.

Comment: Making values null was the only way I could think of to get this logic to work at the time, I'm pretty new to this.
So simply remove all of the "wallThingArray[q] = nulls"?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, I used a `break` to break out of the loop instead of the nulls. The null stuff could work as well, but you'd have to adjust the code I gave.